# Prove that $\dim_{R/(p)}(p^nM/p^{n+1}M)=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and $P$ a be a set of representatives of classes of irreducible elements.

Let $M=R/(q^r)$ with $q\in P\setminus \{p\}$ and $r\in \mathbb N$. I want to show that

$$\dim_{R/(p)}(p^nM/p^{n+1}M)=0\text{ for all }n\in \mathbb N.$$

In the proof in our script, they used the fact that

$$p^nM=(Rp^n+Rq^r)M.$$

I don't understand why this is true. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

That is because, more generally, given two ideals $I$ and $J$ in a ring $R$, one has 
$$I\cdot R/J=(I+J)/J.\tag1$$
This relation yields here
$$p^n M=p^n\cdot R/(q^r)=(p^nR+q^rR)/(q^r)=R/(q^r), $$
since the ideals $(p^n)$ and $(q^r)$  are coprime.

*Proof of $\;(1)$* :

$ I\cdot R/J=\{\,i+J\mid i\in I\,\}$

$ (I+J)/J=\{\,i+j+J\mid i\in I,\, j\in J\,\}=\{\,i+(j+J)\mid i\in I,\, j\in J\,\}$.

Just observe that $j+J=J$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can you prove the first equality?

Comment: @Marc: I've added the details.

Comment: Thanks, we have $I\cdot R/J=\{i+J|i\in I\}$ because each $i$ times some $r\in R$ lies in $I$, right? (Since $I$ is an ideal in $R$).

Comment: Yes because $I$ is an ideal in $R$.